# select an option with image o buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have 3 buttons (can be images too) I need to select only one of them and the one that is selected changes color.

Some reference guide or help to implement.

[see image of how it would be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq5L7.jpg)

**Similar to Waze report:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOiLe.jpg

Comment: When one is "selected", deselect the other two?

Comment: All at the beginning are not selected, when I select an option it must change color. Later with a button, actions will be taken according to the selected option. Similar to Waze report: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOiLe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement it, example assuming you have 3 options in the segment, to receive the selected data you can use the following code in an IB:

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionSegment: UISegmentedControl!

var optionSelect = String()

@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    switch optionSegment.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        optionSelect = "Select option 1"
        print(optionSelect)
    case 1:
        optionSelect = "Select option 2"
         print(optionSelect)
    default:
        optionSelect = "Select option 3"
        print(optionSelect)
    }
}
```

To use it outside of the function, you can use

```
let dataSelect = optionSegment.titleForSegment(at: optionSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
print(dataSelect)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use a UISegmentedControl. It consists of multiple buttons only one of which is selected at a time. It can be customized very heavily, so you can have the button images be one color when selected and another color when not selected.

This is a fairly standard UISegmentedControl:

[image]

This is a heavily customized UISegmentedControl:

[image]

As you can see, you can make the segments look however you like, and "the one that is selected changes color".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already implementing it https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEczj.png